# LOB manipulation in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

can someone please point out what is wrong with this code.

```
declare 
locations CLOB;
offset NUMBER :=1;
begin
  if locations is null then 
    dbms_output.put_line('location is null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('location is not null');
  end if;
  --assign an empty CLOB
  locations := empty_clob();
  --locations := dbms_lob.createTemporary();

  if locations is null then 
    dbms_output.put_line('location is null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('location is not null and length of the lob is: '||dbms_lob.getlength(locations));
  end if;
  --write something
  dbms_lob.open(locations,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  dbms_lob.write(locations,length('i am not alone'),1,'i am not alone');
  --add more lines
  dbms_lob.writeappend(locations,length('i am not alone'),'i am not alone');
  dbms_lob.close(locations);

end;
/
```

I am getting error 22275. 00000 -  "invalid LOB locator specified"
Not sure why I am getting this since I have already initialized the CLOB "locations" using EMPTY_CLOB() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [for `empty_clob()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EMPTY_BLOB-EMPTY_CLOB.html#GUID-551B5A7C-A03B-4B2E-80EF-DAA8574CF160) notes the restriction:

> You cannot use the locator returned from this function as a parameter to the `DBMS_LOB` package or the OCI.

and if you follow the link from that section [you can also see](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/working-with-LOBs.html#GUID-F61CA075-8CB1-4E0B-B538-D886F6CAE263):

> Running the `EMPTY_BLOB()` or `EMPTY_CLOB()` function in and of itself does not raise an exception. However, using a LOB locator that was set to empty to access or manipulate the LOB value in any PL/SQL `DBMS_LOB` or OCI function raises an exception.
>
> Valid places where empty LOB locators may be used include the `VALUES` clause of an `INSERT` statement and the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

You seem to have attempted to use `createtemporary` as that is commented out; but you've called it as a function not a procedure. You can use this form instead:

```
dbms_lob.createtemporary(locations, false);
```

So:

```
set serveroutput on

declare 
  locations CLOB;
  offset NUMBER :=1;
begin
  if locations is null then 
    dbms_output.put_line('location is null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('location is not null');
  end if;
  --assign an empty CLOB
--  locations := empty_clob();
--  locations := dbms_lob.createTemporary();
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(locations, false);

  if locations is null then 
    dbms_output.put_line('location is null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('location is not null and length of the lob is: '||dbms_lob.getlength(locations));
  end if;
  --write something
  dbms_lob.open(locations,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  dbms_lob.write(locations,length('i am not alone'),1,'i am not alone');
  --add more lines
  dbms_lob.writeappend(locations,length('i am not alone'),'i am not alone');
  dbms_lob.close(locations);

  -- added this for fun
  if locations is null then 
    dbms_output.put_line('location is null');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('location is not null and length of the lob is: '||dbms_lob.getlength(locations));
  end if;

end;
/
```

which gets output:

```
location is null
location is not null and length of the lob is: 0
location is not null and length of the lob is: 28


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, but with `dbms_lob.createtemporary(locations, true);`. Do you have an opinion on when to cache temporary lobs?

Comment: @kfinity - not really, not sure I've ever quite understood the caching. For brief manipulation like this I'm not sure what difference it makes. If the CLOB is going to end up being written to a table then having it in the buffer cache might speed that up - but again I'm really not sure. Using false means you don't need to think about duration, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

This code means something silimar to *Get a system constant named `empty lob` and try to write something other into it*. It fails. Why? :)

Replace `locations := empty_lob()` with `dbms_lob.createTemporary(locations, true);` and your code will work.